# PHP upload files on a selected folder

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

In my PHP application, user needs to upload files in proper folder. I have implemented (as described here) the system that allows to upload documents in a proper folder, but I need to do some modifications. User can upload different kind of files, so I've created folders for each kind of file to upload. So, I need that, after file selection, user can select the folder in which file must be uploaded. How can I do it?

EDIT: I think it is needed some clarification. The folder structure that I need to create is the following:

```
- Folder
-- Subfolder
--- Sub-subfolder

- base_folder
-- folderOfUser1
---  folderOfKind1
---  folderOfKind2
---  folderOfKindN

-- folderOfUser2
---  folderOfKind1
---  folderOfKind2
---  folderOfKindN

-- folderOfUserN 
---  folderOfKind1
---  folderOfKind2
---  folderOfKindN
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to scan a user's directory and list all of the user's folders in an option-form. That way it will be possible for the user himself to select the folder and upload the file in this certain directory.

However, in your case a certain file has to be uploaded to one specific folder. Why rely on the user's good intentions? The application should be perfectly capable to detect the type of the file and upload it to the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should autoselect the path for the file to be saved?

You could save the file in some temporary folder like you do it now, than check for the type of file form the server side because you shouln't rely on the data give in the mime type or other classification you want to do.

Then move the file form the temp folder to the right destination. You could put the path as  string together `$path = "/files/".$username."/".$type."/";`

Comment: If you need help with the implementation you could ask anyway. I don't know your existing code and your classification for the files.

Comment: Right now i'm using js tree and PHP upload functions to upload all files in a same folder. The file should be upload in a selected folder